# Why fixing scale parameter to 1 not work for a given data?

Tags: scipy, statistics, weibull

I have a data which is the interval days of customers purchasing products in furniture category. I try to estimate the shape and scale params by scipy.stat.weibull_min function. This fits a three-parameter Weibull, with the usual shape and scale and a shift (location) parameter.

First, I tried fixing shape parameter to be 1 as input (set f0=1) and we shall get the scale parameter in condition of shape=1. From the output below we can find that it works since the shape parameter estimated is 1.

```
shape, loc, scale = scipy.stats.weibull_min.fit(data,floc=1, f0=1) 
#constrain shape to be 1  
loc:1    shape:1  scale:90.85
```

However, when I try to constrain the scale parameter to be 1 in order to get shape parameter in condition of scale=1, it does not work(the output scale parameter is ~75 instead of 1). So I am confused why it doesn't work.

```
shape, loc, scale = scipy.stats.weibull_min.fit(data,floc=1,scale=1)
#constrain scale to be 1  
loc:1    shape:0.7318249351  scale:75.22852953
```

In the scipy.stats official document, scale=1 as input seems default setting. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html

Comment: This was answered by user333700 in the first comment to your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022955/why-are-the-parameters-of-weibull-not-unique-for-a-given-data

Comment: Well. He seems not explain why I should do 'scale=1' and why the output scale is not 1.

Comment: He says use `fscale=1`.  The `f` is important, just like the `f` in `floc` when you fix the location to be 1.

Comment: Many thanks. Since there is no instruction about floc and fscale in offical doc, I thought it was just an param from old version of scipy.  Besides, when I set fscale=1, it not fits well for original data. I compare the three methods and find that weibull_min.fit(data,floc=1,scale=1) fits best, which just not fix scale nor shape neither.  The returned two params are close to the result from R.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html   This page explains the fit function completely.