# Computing the confidence intervals for the lambda parameter of an exponential distribution in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, confidence-interval, data-fitting, scipy.stats

Suppose I have a sample, which I have reason to believe follows an exponential distribution. I want to estimate the distributions parameter (lambda) and some indication of the confidence. Either the confidence interval or the standard error would be fine. Sadly, `scipy.stats.expon.fit` does not seem to permit that. Here's an example, I will use lambda=1/120=0.008333 for the test data:

```
""" Generate test data"""
import scipy.stats
test_data = scipy.stats.expon(scale=120).rvs(size=3000)

""" Scipy.stats fit"""
fit = scipy.stats.expon.fit(test_data)
print("\nExponential parameters:", fit, " Specifically lambda: ", 1/fit[1], "\n")

# Exponential parameters: (0.0066790678905608875, 116.8376079908356)  Specifically lambda:  0.008558887991599736
```

The [answer to a similar question about gamma-distributed data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31365801) suggests using `GenericLikelihoodModel` from the `statsmodels` module. While I can confirm that this works nicely for gamma-distributed data, it does not for exponential distributions, because the optimization apparently results in a non-invertible Hessian matrix. This results either from non-finite elements in the Hessian or from `np.linalg.eigh` producing non-positive eigenvalues for the Hessian. ([Source code here; HessianInversionWarning is raised in the `fit` method of the `LikelihoodModel` class.](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/base/model.html)).

```
""" Statsmodel fit"""
from statsmodels.base.model import GenericLikelihoodModel

class Expon(GenericLikelihoodModel):
    nparams = 2
    def loglike(self, params):
        return scipy.stats.expon.logpdf(self.endog, *params).sum()


res = Expon(test_data).fit(start_params=fit)
res.df_model = len(fit)
res.df_resid = len(test_data) - len(fit)
print(res.summary())

#Optimization terminated successfully.
#         Current function value: 5.760785
#         Iterations: 38
#         Function evaluations: 76
#/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/numdiff.py:352: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
#  hess[i, j] = (f(*((x + ee[i, :] + ee[j, :],) + args), **kwargs)
#/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py:547: HessianInversionWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available
#  warn('Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params '
#/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:903: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
#  return (a < x) & (x < b)
#/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:903: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
#  return (a < x) & (x < b)
#/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:1912: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
#  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= _a)
#                                Expon Results                                 
#==============================================================================
#Dep. Variable:                      y   Log-Likelihood:                -17282.
#Model:                          Expon   AIC:                         3.457e+04
#Method:            Maximum Likelihood   BIC:                         3.459e+04
#Date:                Thu, 06 Aug 2020                                         
#Time:                        13:55:24                                         
#No. Observations:                3000                                         
#Df Residuals:                    2998                                         
#Df Model:                           2                                         
#==============================================================================
#                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#par0           0.0067        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
#par1         116.8376        nan        nan        nan         nan         nan
#==============================================================================
```

This seems to happen every single time, so it might be something related to exponentially-distributed data.

Is there some other possible approach? Or am I maybe missing something or doing something wrong here?

**Edit:** It turns out, I was doing something wrong, namely, I wrongly had

```
test_data = scipy.stats.expon(120).rvs(size=3000)
```

instead of

```
test_data = scipy.stats.expon(scale=120).rvs(size=3000)
```

and was correspondingly looking at the forst element of the fit tuple while I should have been looking at the second.

As a result, the two other options I considered ([manually computing the fit and confidence intervals following the standard procedure described on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Confidence_intervals)) and using `scikits.bootstrap` as [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37349695) actually does work and is part of the solution I'll add in a minute and not of the problem.

Comment: My first guess is that there is a problem when "loc" is estimated because it shifts the support of the distribution. Try fixing loc=0 and only estimate lambda.

Comment: @Josef Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I made much worse mistake, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the edited question, part of the problem was that I was looking at the wrong parameter when creating the sample and again in the fit.

What remains is that `scipy.stats.expon.fit` does not offer the possibility to compute confidence or errors and that using `GenericLikelihoodModel` from the `statsmodels` module as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31365801) fails because of a malformed Hessian.

There are, however three approaches that do work:

**1. Using the simple inference procedure for confidence intervals in exponential data as given in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Confidence_intervals)**

```
""" Maximum likelihood"""
import numpy as np
ML_lambda = 1 / np.mean(test_data)
print("\nML lambda: {0:8f}".format(ML_lambda))

#ML lambda: 0.008558

""" Bias corrected ML"""
ML_BC_lambda = ML_lambda - ML_lambda / (len(test_data) - 1)
print("\nML bias-corrected lambda: {0:8f}".format(ML_BC_lambda))

#ML bias-corrected lambda: 0.008556
```

Computation of the confidence intervals::

```
""" Maximum likelihood 95% confidence"""
CI_distance = ML_BC_lambda * 1.96/(len(test_data)**0.5)
print("\nLambda with confidence intervals: {0:8f} +/- {1:8f}".format(ML_BC_lambda, CI_distance))
print("Confidence intervals: ({0:8f}, {1:9f})".format(ML_BC_lambda - CI_distance, ML_BC_lambda + CI_distance))

#Lambda with confidence intervals: 0.008556 +/- 0.000306
#Confidence intervals: (0.008249,  0.008862)
```

Second option with this: In addition, the confidence interval equation should also be valid for a lambda estimate produced by a different such as the one from `scipy.stats.expon.fit`. (I thought that the fitting procedure in `scipy.stats.expon.fit` was more reliable, but it turns out it is actually the same, without the bias correction (see above).)

```
""" Maximum likelihood 95% confidence based on scipy.stats fit"""
scipy_stats_lambda = 1 / fit[1]
scipy_stats_CI_distance = scipy_stats_lambda * 1.96/(len(test_data)**0.5)
print("\nOr, based on scipy.stats fit:")
print("Lambda with confidence intervals: {0:8f} +/- {1:8f}".format(scipy_stats_lambda, scipy_stats_CI_distance))
print("Confidence intervals: ({0:8f}, {1:9f})".format(scipy_stats_lambda - scipy_stats_CI_distance, 
                                                                scipy_stats_lambda + scipy_stats_CI_distance))

#Or, based on scipy.stats fit:
#Lambda with confidence intervals: 0.008559 +/- 0.000306
#Confidence intervals: (0.008253,  0.008865)
```

**2. Bootstrapping with `scikits.bootstrap` following [the suggestion in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37349695)**
This yields an `InstabilityWarning: Some values were NaN; results are probably unstable (all values were probably equal)`, so this should be treated a bit skeptically.

```
""" Bootstrapping with scikits"""
print("\n")
import scikits.bootstrap as boot
bootstrap_result = boot.ci(test_data, scipy.stats.expon.fit)
print(bootstrap_result)

#tmp/expon_fit_test.py:53: InstabilityWarning: Some values were NaN; results are probably unstable (all values were probably equal)
#  bootstrap_result = boot.ci(test_data, scipy.stats.expon.fit)
#[[6.67906789e-03 1.12615588e+02]
# [6.67906789e-03 1.21127091e+02]]
```

**3. Using `rpy2`**

```
""" Using r modules with rpy2"""
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
MASS = importr('MASS')
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
rpy_fit = MASS.fitdistr(test_data, "exponential")
rpy_estimate = rpy_fit.rx("estimate")[0][0]
rpy_sd = rpy_fit.rx("sd")[0][0]
rpy_lower = rpy_estimate - 2*rpy_sd
rpy_upper = rpy_estimate + 2*rpy_sd
print("\nrpy2 fit: \nLambda={0:8f} +/- {1:8f}, CI: ({2:8f}, {3:8f})".format(rpy_estimate, rpy_sd, rpy_lower, rpy_upper))

#rpy2 fit: 
#Lambda=0.008558 +/- 0.000156, CI: (0.008246, 0.008871)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already found a solution to your problem, but here is a solution based on OpenTURNS. I think it relies on bootstrapping under the hood.

OpenTURNS requires you to reshape the data so that it is clear we are dealing with 3000 one-dimensional points and not a single 3000-dimensional point.

```
test_data = test_data.reshape(-1, 1)
```

The rest is rather straightforward.

```
import openturns as ot

confidence_level = 0.9

params_ci = ot.ExponentialFactory().buildEstimator(test_data).getParameterDistribution().computeBilateralConfidenceInterval(confidence_level)

lambda_ci = [params_ci.getLowerBound()[0], params_ci.getUpperBound()[0]] 
# the index 0 means we are interested in the CI on lambda

print(lambda_ci)
```

I got the following output (but it depends on the random seed):

```
[0.008076302149561718, 0.008688296487447742]
```