# Python curve fitting using MLE and obtaining standard errors for parameter estimates

Tags: python, curve-fitting, statistics-bootstrap, mle, standard-error

**The original problem**

While translating MATLAB code to python, I have the function [`[parmhat,parmci] = gpfit(x,alpha)`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/gpfit.html). This function fits a Generalized Pareto Distribution and returns the parameter estimates, `parmhat`, and the `100(1-alpha)%` confidence intervals for the parameter estimates, `parmci`.

> MATLAB also provides the function [gplike](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/gplike.html) that returns `acov`, the inverse of Fisher's information matrix. This matrix contains the asymptotic variances on the diagonal when using MLE. I have the feeling this can be coupled to the confidence intervals as well, however my statistics background is not strong enough to understand if this is true.

What I am looking for is Python code that gives me the `parmci` values (I can get the `parmhat` values by using `scipy.stats.genpareto.fit`). I have been scouring Google and Stackoverflow for 2 days now, and I cannot find any approach that works for me.

> While I am specifically working with the Generalized Pareto Distribution, I think this question can apply to many more (if not all) distributions that `scipy.stats` has.

**My data:** I am interested in the shape and scale parameters of the generalized pareto fit, the location parameter should be fixed at `0` for my fit.

**What I have done so far**

**scipy.stats** While `scipy.stats` provides nice fitting performance, this library does not offer a way to calculate the confidence interval on the parameter estimates of the distribution fitter.

**scipy.optimize.curve_fit** As an alternative I have seen suggested to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` instead, as this does provide the estimated covariance of the parameter estimated. However that fitting method uses least squares, whereas I need to use MLE and I didn't see a way to make `curve_fit` use MLE instead. Therefore it seems that I cannot use `curve_fit`.

**statsmodel.GenericLikelihoodModel** Next I found a suggestion to use [`statsmodel.GenericLikelihoodModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359017/how-to-get-error-estimates-for-fit-parameters-in-scipy-stats-gamma-fit). The original question there used a gamma distribution and asked for a non-zero location parameter. I altered the code to:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.base.model import GenericLikelihoodModel
from scipy.stats import genpareto


# Data contains 24 experimentally obtained values
data = np.array([3.3768732 , 0.19022354, 2.5862942 , 0.27892331, 2.52901677,
       0.90682787, 0.06842895, 0.90682787, 0.85465385, 0.21899145,
       0.03701204, 0.3934396 , 0.06842895, 0.27892331, 0.03701204,
       0.03701204, 2.25411215, 3.01049545, 2.21428639, 0.6701813 ,
       0.61671203, 0.03701204, 1.66554224, 0.47953739, 0.77665706,
       2.47123239, 0.06842895, 4.62970341, 1.0827188 , 0.7512669 ,
       0.36582134, 2.13282122, 0.33655947, 3.29093622, 1.5082936 ,
       1.66554224, 1.57606579, 0.50645878, 0.0793677 , 1.10646119,
       0.85465385, 0.00534871, 0.47953739, 2.1937636 , 1.48512994,
       0.27892331, 0.82967374, 0.58905024, 0.06842895, 0.61671203,
       0.724393  , 0.33655947, 0.06842895, 0.30709881, 0.58905024,
       0.12900442, 1.81854273, 0.1597266 , 0.61671203, 1.39384127,
       3.27432715, 1.66554224, 0.42232511, 0.6701813 , 0.80323855,
       0.36582134])
params = genpareto.fit(data, floc=0, scale=0) 
# HOW TO ESTIMATE/GET ERRORS FOR EACH PARAM?

print(params)
print('\n')


class Genpareto(GenericLikelihoodModel):

    nparams = 2

    def loglike(self, params):
        # params = (shape, loc, scale)
        return genpareto.logpdf(self.endog, params[0], 0, params[2]).sum()


res = Genpareto(data).fit(start_params=params)
res.df_model = 2
res.df_resid = len(data) - res.df_model
print(res.summary())
```

This gives me a somewhat reasonable fit:

- Scipy stats fit: `(0.007194143471555344, 0, 1.005020562073944)`
- Genpareto fit:    `(0.00716650293, 8.47750397e-05, 1.00504535)`

However in the end I get an error when it tries to calculate the covariance:

`HessianInversionWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available`

> If I do `return genpareto.logpdf(self.endog, *params).sum()` I get a worse fit compared to scipy stats.

**Bootstrapping** Lastly I found mentions to bootstrapping. While I did sort of understand what's the idea behind it, I have no clue how to implement it. What I understand is that you should resample N times (1000 for example) from your data set (24 points in my case). Then do a fit on that sub-sample, and register the fit result. Then do a statistical analysis on the N results, i.e. calculating mean, std_dev and then confidence interval, like [Estimate confidence intervals for parameters of distribution in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481279/estimate-confidence-intervals-for-parameters-of-distribution-in-python) or [Compute a confidence interval from sample data assuming unknown distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392978/compute-a-confidence-interval-from-sample-data-assuming-unknown-distribution/66008548#66008548). I even found some [old MATLAB documentation](http://www.mbfys.ru.nl/%7Erobvdw/CNP04/LAB_ASSIGMENTS/LAB05_CN05/MATLAB2007b/stats/html/gparetodemo.html) on the calculations behind gpfit explaining this.

However I need my code to run fast, and I am not sure if any implementation that I make will do this calculation fast.

**Conclusions** Does anyone know of a Python function that calculates this in an efficient manner, or can point me to a topic where this has been explained already in a way that it works for my case at least?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with GenericLikelihoodModel and I came across this post (https://pystatsmodels.narkive.com/9ndGFxYe/mle-error-warning-inverting-hessian-failed-maybe-i-cant-use-matrix-containers) which suggests using different starting parameter values to get a result with positive hessian. Solved my problem.